# Listbox inputting old selections not new selections into SQLServer on update

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I have an issue with a couple of listboxes I have on a webforms asp.net web pageand any help is much appreciated.

I have a page that allows an insert of a user profile and then allows the updating of that new profile.

On the update, when the user selects some new listitems to update the old listitems that have set the listbox, the code is somehow adding a listitem to the previous list of items (the ones from the database) in an appending fashion and not overwriting the old values with the new list of selected listitems.

The following is how I coded the setup.

1. I have a listbox that is being dynamically populated when a form loads -
2. This is being populated from a SQLServer 2008 R2 database when the form loads -
3. When the user selects one or more of the values in the listbox these are input into the database as a comma delimited string -
4. The newly inputed values are pulled from the database and set the same listbox with selected items -
5. When the user selects some new listitems to update the list, the code is somehow adding a listitem to the previous list of items (the ones from the database) in an appending fashion and not overwriting the old values with the new list of selected listitems.

p.s sorry there is no code as the editor is not letting me post any..please refer to the link below for the full post

Thank you.

Comment: Hi,Full post can be view here - http://31.222.187.42/hca-app/post.txt

Comment: when the pageloads? r u sure to implement it under `!IsPostBack` ??

Comment: Thanks a million Praveen, that worked a treat!!

Comment: mark it as answered below so that this question goes answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `!IsPostBack` property in `page_load`